# A copying nightmare, choosing files to copy based on files in another folder

Tags: r, copying

I have a bit of an issue with using copy.file.

I need to copy .tif files from a directory with several subdirectories (where the .tif files are) based on names of those in another file directory. I have the following code (which is almost working)

```
ValidatedDirectory <- "C:/Users/JS22/Desktop/R_Experiments/Raw_Folder_Testa/Validated"
RawDirectory <- "C:/Users/JS22/Desktop/R_Experiments/Raw_Folder_Testa/Raw"
OutputDirectory <- "C:/Users/JS22/Desktop/R_Experiments/Raw_Folder_Testa/Ouputfolder"

ValidatedImages <- list.files(ValidatedDirectory)


# this is to remove the extra bit that is added onto the validated images [working]
pattern <- gsub("_hc", "", ValidatedImages) 
pattern <- paste(gsub("([.|()\\^{}+$*?]|\\[|\\])", "\\\\\\1", pattern), collapse="|")

# this bit tackles finding the relevant files based on the ValidatedImages
filesinRAW <- list.files(
  path = RawDirectory,
  recursive = TRUE,
  include.dirs = FALSE,
  full.names = FALSE)
filesinRAW <- as.list(filesinRAW)

# this removes subdirectory prefix in front of the file and .tif which confuses it
filesinRAW <- as.list(gsub("\\d\\d\\d\\d/", "", filesinRAW)) 
filesinRaw <- as.list(gsub(".tif", "", filesinRAW))

tocopy <- grep(filesinRAW, pattern = pattern, value = TRUE)
tocopy <- as.list(tocopy)
tocopy <- as.list(gsub(".tif", "", tocopy))

setwd(RawDirectory)

file.copy(from = tocopy, to = OutputDirectory, overwrite = TRUE)
```

I get the `No such file or directory` error, the files do exist (obviously), thus I must be doing something wrong with the naming.

I have been having a bash at it for a good while, if helpful I can upload the example data and share the link.

Thanks for any help community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much help from @Emil Bode I have the following solution to the issue (perhaps not the most elegant, but it runs quick enough on 1000s of .tif files.

```
ValidatedDirectory <- "C:/Users/JS22/Desktop/R_Experiments/Raw_Folder_Testa/Validated"
RawDirectory <- "C:/Users/JS22/Desktop/R_Experiments/Raw_Folder_Testa/Raw"
OutputDirectory <- "C:/Users/JS22/Desktop/R_Experiments/Raw_Folder_Testa/Ouputfolder"

ValidatedImages <- list.files(ValidatedDirectory)

pattern <- gsub("_hc", "", ValidatedImages)
pattern <- paste(gsub("([.|()\\^{}+$*?]|\\[|\\])", "\\\\\\1", pattern), collapse="|")

filesinRAW <- list.files(
  path = RawDirectory,
  recursive = TRUE,
  include.dirs = FALSE,
  full.names = FALSE,
  pattern = pattern)

setwd(RawDirectory)

file.copy(from = filesinRAW, to = OutputDirectory, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

When debugging, try to break down your code to see if at each step your variables are still as you're expect them.

That said, I see several problems in your code right now:

- grep works with `pattern` being a length-one regular expression. If you give it multiple regular expressions, it uses the first one (with a warning, which you don't see if you've disabled them).
  To use multiple matches, you can use `apply` and `sapply`: `filesinRAW[apply(sapply(pattern, grepl, x=filesinRAW), 2, any)]`. But see the last point
- grep by default uses pattern as a regular expression, which may break things if your pattern contains characters that are parsed. For example, `grep('^test', '^test')` gives zero results. To check if a string contains a literal string, you can use `grep(..., fixed=TRUE)`
- In the last step, you use `sub(".tif", "", to copy)`, which will *remove* any patterns like .tif. I suppose you meant to *add* .tif again at the end, right now you are trying to copy files without an extension, which won't be found. To add, you can use `paste`.
- In several steps you use `as.list`. Why? In R, everything is vectorised, meaning multiple values are already used. The difference between a list and a vector is that lists can store different kinds of objects, but you're not doing that anyway. As far as I can see, the as.lists don't harm anything, because all the functions will as a first step convert your list back to a character-vector.
- Finally, as far I can see you're first making a list of filenames that need to be copied (`pattern`), that you then compare to a full list of your files. And you try to make them match exactly. Then why use a regular expression? Regular expressions are useful if you just know a part of what your filenames look like, but is that your goal. E.g. if `filename1._hc` is in your ValidatedDirectory, do the files `filename11.tif` and `filename12.tif` need to be copied as well?
  If you're just looking for exact matches, you can directly compare them:
  `tocopy <- tocopy[tocopy %in% pattern]`

But generally, working in R is easy because you can do everything step-by-step, and if you just inspect `tocopy`, you can see whether your call makes sense.

Comment: Fantastic, what a comprehensive answer. I used the as.list function as I have a similar bit of a code for another purpose which only works when as a list. I have left it in there for now. This evening (GMT) I will work through those points. I am fairly new to this side of R and use it predominantly for statistics but know all is possible. Thanks again for your detailed, and very informative answer! Jim